# Upgrading AKS to 1.9

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I have been following an AKS issue on GitHub - https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/103, where users appear to be able to upgrade AKS to 1.9.1 via the CLI.

Regardless of which method I use I cannot force an upgrade on my AKS cluster and it is not yet possible to create a 1.9 cluster from scratch.

This is the command I am using:

```
 az aks upgrade --name $ClusterName --resource-group $ResourceGroup --kubernetes-version $Version --yes
```

Each time I run this I receive the following message:

```
Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The selected orchestrator version is not supported
```

Now I am aware that 1.9 is not officially supported, but it seems to be possible based on the issue raised on GitHub.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the product team for AKS on GitHub:

[image]

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/103#issuecomment-364612288

Answer (score 0):

you have to try to run below command

## az aks upgrade --resource-group rg-01 --name aks-01 --kubernetes-version 1.21.7 --debug